# How can I Filter Data in Google Data Studio based on containing 2 or more input options?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm building a dashboard for a dataset that includes a Location column, and I would like the user to be able to filter based on location. The trouble is that some projects are happening in multiple locations, so that the column is comma separated list of locations, making the normal dropdown filter option cumbersome ("NY, Paris" and "Paris, NY" are treated as different values). While this can be overcome by adding a parameter dropdown box and allowing the user to select an option (say Paris) and then using a Contains function to filter the output, the Parameter drop down box only allows 1 selection to be made. So a search for all project happening in either Paris or New York seems like it would have to be done using 2 separate parameters. Is anyone aware of an elegant workaround for this that will allow multiple selections of locations within a single dropdown.

The inelegant solutions I've come up with are:

1. Use n parameter boxes and cap the locations that can be filtered in a single view at n.
2. Have users input a comma separated list as a parameter, parse that for locations and then show all REGEXP CONTAINS matches of that provided list.

Example dataset showing multiple locations per project in the locations column:

[image]

Edited to add a link to a sample report [here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/2edf27f5-b627-4a3f-91da-79e117562461). The problem, in a nutshell is that I would like people to be able to select 2 or more location parameters so that they don't have to limit themselves to viewing 1 location at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to filter CSVs (Comma Separated Values) is by using the [CSV Filter Control](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/2b0a22a2-3992-49e1-be12-bdc22937daea/page/QPvLB) [Community Visualisation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) (click on the [image: 3] icon on the toolbar and select [image: 4] to view all):

**Data Tab**

- ***Column to filter on***: `Location`
- ***Cross-filtering***: Select (☑) (this ensures that the CSV Filter Control filters other charts based on the value(s) selected)

**Style Tab**

- ***OR instead of AND behaviour***: Select (☑)

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/dde12670-a538-494e-9114-398c3d7314d5) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ocfi_gzxUKqXj98jpBNQgUfAE8iUbCKMyRvy-Z8aFug/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]